# Commutative ring Notes by M. Artin

Tags: books, ac.commutative-algebra

In 1966, Professor Michael Artin gave a course for first-year graduate students at MIT on commutative algebra. In that course he covered many classical topics, (the Spectrum of a commutative ring, localization, something about sheafs, stalks and exact sequences, projective modules, flatness and an exposition about flat descent). There are some lecture notes for that course: I have a photocopied version of the notes (and I've actually used them as a reference more than once). My question is: did Professor Artin ever publish a book that you know is based on that course (or more recent courses he gave on commutative algebra)?

In my university there are several photocopied-copies of that notes (very popular, indeed!) but I really find difficult to read a book that is typed in such a bad way (Notice that the criticism is just typographical! I love the content and the way in which the material was presented!)

Comment: I am reasonably certain he did not, in the sense that I don't see one online.  But why don't you just email him?

Comment: If the answer turns out to be "no", you always have the option of typing them up yourself.  Probably many people would be grateful.

Comment: Dear Pete, of course I would, if I had enough time. But I've been busy in typing the notes of the course that I'm attending now:). Anyway, since I loved the expository style of Professor Artin, I secretly hoped that it was possible to find an "updated" version of that notes (possibly a book).

Comment: @F.Binda: Well, if Artin gave the course in 1966 and still hasn't typed up the notes, perhaps there is no rush.  If you typed them up say 15 months from now, I for one would probably still be interested.

Comment: Dear Qiaochu, I think I'll try to e-mail him (as soon as I find a reasonably recent e-mail address...)

Comment: artin@math.mit.edu

Comment: @F.Binda: Did you ever get an electronic copy of these notes from Professor Artin?

Comment: How can one get a copy of those notes? even if the typography is not great

Comment: Still interested in those notes: has anyone got a copy?